# How to display an ASP.net MVC project version in page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In WinForms, I'd use `Application.ProductVersion`.

I've tried using `System.Reflection.Assembly` in various ways but can never get the version of just the MVC project.

Comment: Do you mean the version of Sysetm.Web.Mvc.dll? Or do you mean something related to the new MVC project template?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provided this code is explicitly in the MVC project (rather than in a helper assembly), you should be able to use `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString(3)`, which returns the major, minor, and revision numbers.  Otherwise you might want to use something like `typeof(HomeController).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString(3)`.

Comment: `GetExecutingAssembly().GetName()` returns `App_Web_ykccwaz0, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`

Comment: Guessing you're running it through the ASP.NET compiler, but the version of the assembly should remain the same.  Your AssemblyInfo has a valid version number set for the assembly, right?

Comment: If I check the properties of the MVC project .dll in the /bin directory, it shows the correct assembly version.

Comment: I've used `typeof(HomeController).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString(3)` and it works

Comment: This is not an answer to the question asked. Application.ProductVersion is NOT the assembly version as specified using the AssemblyVersion attribute. It is the AssemblyInfoVersion attribute. WinForms exposes the product version on the Application object. From what I can see this is not similarly exposed in ASP.NET nor can I find it reflecting against the assembly.